# Prestashop get exactly data and look like product list with custom product id in array?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In Prestashop I want to display all of the data of the products just like the product loop page. For that I have an array of products id. The code s like this

```
$id_lang=Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
$id_products = array(2,3,4,6,7);
$all_products = array();
foreach ($id_products as $id_product ) {
  $product_id = $id_product;
  $link = new Link();
  $image = Image::getCover($product_id);
  $url = $link->getProductLink($product_id);          
  $product = new Product($product_id);
  $imagePath = Link::getImageLink($product->link_rewrite,   $image['id_image'], 'home_default');          
  array_push($all_products, $product);
}

    $this->context->smarty->assign(
        array(
          'all_products' => $all_products,
          'lang_id'      => $id_lang,
          'url'         => $url,
        )
    );
```

and in the smarty I have done my code like this

```
<ul>
 <!-- {$all_products|@print_r} -->
{foreach from=$all_products item=product name=product}

<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3  first-in-line">
    <div class="product-container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <div class="left-block">
            <div class="product-image-container">

                <a class="product_img_link" href="{$url}" title="{$product->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url">
                    <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="" >
                </a> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

Here in the smarty I have done copy and paste `product-list.tpl` files code as I want my custom loop should look exactly like that but it is showing many errors. So can someone kindly tell me how can I get the exactly look of the product list page with products id? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: I see first problem not connected with Prestashop  - $id_products = array(2,3,4,6,7); ... $product_id = $id_product['id_product'];

Comment: @SergiiP sorry I have edited my question. Can you help me out here?

Comment: You need to post "many errors" that you see at the page